# Can not get Group to show up when menu item is selected

Tags: rust, fltk

I have been trying to get menu and submenu items to produce the output desired.  I have tried multiple ways and some work part way and other do not work at all.  Below is my latest try.  The main window shows up and the menu and submenu items can be selected.  I have println! statements in each one and the results show up on the terminal window when selected.  What is not happening is the GROUP is not displaying although I know I am in the area because I get the output from the two println!'s.  What in the world am I doing wrong?????

For those that think I should be learning how to do this myself please point me to some info that I can read to help me solve this problem.  All the information I have found so has all the items in a single thread with no branching.

```
main_win.show();
    main_win.set_callback(move|_| {
        if app::event() == Event::Close {
            s.send(Message::Quit);
        }
    });

    while app.wait() {
        use Message::*;
        if let Some(msg) = r.recv() {
            match msg {
                Preference => {
                    println!("In Preference area");
                }
                Quit => {
                    app.quit();
                }

                Wallets => {
                    println!("In Wallets area");

                    let mut wall_group =
                        fltk::group::Group::new(50, 90, 500, 300, "Wallet Data Add/Change/Delete");
                    
                    wall_group.set_frame(FrameType::FlatBox);
                    wall_group.set_color(Color::by_index(2));
                    wall_group.end();
                                       
                    let wall_name = fltk::input::Input::new(180, 105, 170, 20, "Wallet Name:");
                    wall_group.add(&wall_name);
                    let wall_username =
                        fltk::input::Input::new(180, 130, 170, 20, "Wallet Username:");
                    wall_group.add(&wall_username);
                    let wall_password =
                        fltk::input::Input::new(180, 155, 170, 20, "Wallet Password:");
                    wall_group.add(&wall_password);
                    let btn_wall_add = fltk::button::Button::new(180, 190, 60, 20, "Add");
                    wall_group.add(&btn_wall_add);
                    let btn_wall_delete = fltk::button::Button::new(260, 190, 60, 20, "Delete");
                    wall_group.add(&btn_wall_delete);
                    println!("In Wallets area 2");
                }
```

Comment: Maybe this example can help you [(see example)](https://github.com/wyhinton/FLTK-RS-Examples/tree/master/group_background)

Comment: That is a good example but the code is in line (all in the same block).  I need to have an inner block or in a function call that contains the GROUP build and show.

Comment: do you call a drawing function at a moment or another ? I am sorry i try to help but i've never use FLTK before

Comment: In the above code I look for a menu selection.  then based on the selection I want to create a GROUP window that contains the information I am trying to get from the user.  I just can't figure out how to tell the GROUP to show up.

Comment: You never call the draw function, and tell it what to draw,  so nothing shows up. See the example that i gave in previous comment, you have `group.draw(...)` call line 14

Answer (score 0):

Currently the instantiated group isn’t parented directly or indirectly to the window. You can use window.add(&wall_group) to add it (or use insert). Better yet, you can already create the group, keep it hidden, then call show in the Wallets event.